# Как запретить ввод Русских букв и символов в множественных TextBox'aх?

Tags: c#

У меня на форме имеется много текстбоксов 10 - 15 шт, как мне в каждом из них запретить вводить Русские буквы?

У меня есть метод который позволяет запрещать ввод Русских букв в текстбокс

В событие `TextBox_KeyPress` записываю следующее:

```
if ((e.KeyChar < 'A' || e.KeyChar > 'Z') && (e.KeyChar < 'a' || e.KeyChar > 'z') && (e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && e.KeyChar != '_' && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Но если много текстбоксов, то как это всё совместить?

Или же другого выхода нет и придётся каждый раз подписываться на `KeyPress` и повторять код ?

[**Обновление**]

Частично решил проблему так:

```
 private void TextBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
    char Key = e.KeyChar;
    if ((Key < 'A' || Key > 'Z') && (Key < 'a' || Key > 'z') && (Key < '0' || Key > '9') && Key != '_' && Key != (char)Keys.Back)
    {
       e.Handled = true;
    }
 }
```

И в загрузчике формы подписываю событие

```
this.TextBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.TextBoxOnTextChanged);
```

Comment: _Все_ текстбоксы подписать на _один_ метод. PS: но это не спасёт от вставки русских букв из буфера обмена (Ctrl+V или мышкой). Используйте событие `TextChanged`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Да Вы правы, Русские буквы всё равно вставляются, а если использовать `TextChanged` то как изменить сам обработчик?